# How to deal with tradeoff in tree structure between mutability vs performance

Tags: javascript, tree, immutability

It seems that I'm bumping into one question after the other when it relates to implementing the tree structure library but this is a crucial one.

Assume that I have two core constructors: `Tree` and `Node`.
Whereas the Tree object will have methods to manage the tree, and get references to Node objects.

The problem I can't seem to get around is that it seems that the Node objects (and their children) have to be immutable. What we don't want is that the user of the library can mutate the internal structure:

```
var childNodes = Tree.findNode(5).children; 
var node = children[0]; 
node = "overwrite with something";
```

or

```
var parentNode = Tree.findNode(5).parent; 
parentNode.children = { text: "Doesn't realize this will change the original node's children" };
```

It will affect the current tree and screw up the inner workings.

Alternatively, if I would assume to work with immutable objects / arrays, it implies continuous copies.
Assume that I want to move 10 random nodes over a tree structure to (under) a single node. That means making copies and reassign entire arrays in order to mutate them. (We don't know how long the arrays will be!). This seems enormous overkill for what doesn't have cost with mutable data structures. It feel in my spine that it will also be a lot more cumbersome code-wise.

I've tried many workarounds, but ultimately end up with the same dilemma.
How do I solve this?

Edit: almost forgot to mention that I use arrays as node children, because order is important for my use case.

Comment: have you tried using object getters/setters to create a form of immutability? That's how I managed it with [relational-json](https://github.com/SebastienDaniel/relational-json). Look at the table methods, they cover arrays, too. And the perf. is quite decent. Nowhere near mutable objects, but still sufficient for production use.

Comment: @SebastienDaniel The thing is that I don't see how it changes the problem. In the sense is that (I think) it will still return a reference when it concerns objects, and doesn't make it immutable. I've read that getters/setters are very costly, which I'm not sure is a good thing with dealing with a lot of nodes...

Comment: They "were" very costly when they first came out, the compilers have gotten much better.
Granted, if you're returning objects, and not just primitives, then you may want to look into [ImmutableJS](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/)

Comment: @SebastienDaniel That's possible. Still the same problem for me... mutable whether with getters or not results in the same problem, immutable means copying potentially long immutable arrays of immutable objects. I'm currently doing some reading but currently haven't found a satisfactory solution... Have started watching something promising here: https://vimeo.com/86694423

Comment: I suppose at some point you have to choose between the trade-off of simplicity & performance, vs taking your library users for incompetent developers. JS remains a scripting language, that is loosely typed and dynamic... In any case, keep us posted if you find any viable routes, I'm curious.

Comment: @SebastienDaniel It's possible, thanks for your input. The video starts to look VERY promising actually but I'm just at the start. Almost have to go to bed but I'll keep looking the coming days and keep you posted. If I have found satisfactory answer, I will write a response.

Comment: I don't get where in your tree you have long arrays. Trees are a pretty efficient data structure that is easy to write with immutability.

Comment: I don't get what immutability has to do with incompetent library users messing with internals?

Comment: @Bergi I wanted to implementat tree structures in the form `{ id: 1, text: "root", children: [ { id: 2, text: "text2", children: [ ] } ] }` and allow the three basic forms of iteration to traverse the tree (pre, post, level order). Do you mean I should use nested immutable objects instead and access by key? What's your view?

Comment: @KimGysen: How could a tree be structured if not nested? Not sure what you mean by "access by key".

Comment: Indeed I was too quick. Nope that doesn't solve it... the video I'm watching seems pretty interesting.  vimeo.com/86694423 If you have thoughts, I'd love to hear. Right I forgot to mention, also I'm not dealing with binary trees.

Comment: @Bergi could we discuss Immutability & "users" on SO chat (this isn't the best place)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to go with immutable node objects; this to disallow the lib user to accidentally screw up the internal workings.

My concern was about the performance that would suffer because of making too many copies. As I learned, there is a performant way to deal with Immutable objects, which is what [Immutablejs](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) provides out of the box.
After having watched a few presentations and having read the documentation, I was pleasantly surprised by their extensive API that will provide the required flexibility.

Strategy is to offer the user choice between returning either Immutable objects or native Javascript objects (when working with React, Immutable seems to be a very popular choice). But internally the library will use Immutable objects.

@SebstienDaniel Thanks for the suggestion, it was spot on.